# Change background color of selected ScopeBar in UISearchBar

Tags: swift, uikit

I am new to Swift and now trying to change the background color of the selected ScopeBar Button. Now it is white color, I am trying to change it to another one. Below you can find a code, that I am using to add a UISearchBar and configure it.
[ScopeBarButtonSelected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8yVB.png)

```
private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "TopicColor")
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance(idiom: .phone)
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "TopicColor")
    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Movie", "Series"]
    
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor(named: "Color-1")

    let placeholderAppearance = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
    placeholderAppearance.textColor = UIColor.white
    
    let searchTextAppearance = UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
    searchTextAppearance.textColor = UIColor.white

    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    
    searchController.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "Color-1")!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar/1624290-setscopebarbuttonbackgroundimage

Answer (score -1):

UISearchBar contains the UITextField which can be identified through key “searchField”.

Therefore we can access the UITextField through the key and perform necessary changes with it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
   textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

for more detail see:
https://mobikul.com/customise-the-uisearchbar-in-swift/